# Is there an ExpressionEngine SEO optimization plugin like Yoast?

Tags: seo

Is there an ExpressionEngine SEO optimization plugin like Yoast for WordPress? I need to be able to optimize blog posts for search.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. however, you are more free in EE to setup fields to tailor your needs. More than in WP

Comment: Can you give any examples @Jelle Dijkstra? Thanks

Comment: What he means is that you can make custom fields for seo titles, and descriptions as well as anything else really.

Comment: What michael says. I guess what you mean is the advice part of the yoast module. That is not available in EE. However, the basic seo rules it uses are not that difficult to learn. And when you have a bit of experience writing seo optimised text, it'll come naturally.

Answer (score 1):

[SEO Lite](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/seolite) is a lightweight module which creates SEO tab on publish page where you can add you seo title and descriptions.

You can also give the channel fields to include it in SEO meta for og:title or og:desc or og:image. Visit the doc [here](http://wedoaddons.com/seo-lite/extra-tags)